# How to overlay an full page button which when pressed closes the broswer

Tags: javascript, html

So in my POS System, I have a customer display which is an fullscreen html internet explorer window with the html locally hosted. Sometimes this window jumps back in front of the POS software and as the POS is left click only I cant close it. Would I be able to put a full screen transparent button in front of the html content so that whenever that screen is clicked it will close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use CSS to position your button at the center of the browser viewport.

- Use `position:fixed;` to keep the button positioned relative to the viewport.
- Use `z-index: 9999;` to keep the button always on top of you HTML page.
- Use `left` and `top` properties to position your button, `calc` allows to dynamically calculate CSS property values, with `50vw` you say to browser to position at 50% of the viewport width, 50px is 50% of width and height for your button, so it will be always positioned at the center of the viewport.

```css
#close{
  position:fixed;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: calc(50vw - 50px);
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<button id="close" type="button">Close Window!</button>
```